# Correct way to generate an SDLK_LEFT SDL_Event?

Tags: macos, events, keyboard, sdl

I would like to generate an SDL_Event but it doesn't seem work. Here's my code to generate:

```
Uint8* keys; 

SDL_Event ev;
ev.type = SDL_KEYDOWN;
ev.key.state = SDL_PRESSED;
ev.key.keysym.sym = SDLK_LEFT;

SDL_PushEvent(&ev); 
keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
```

Later I'm checking if it's there:

```
if(keys)
{
    if(keys[SDLK_LEFT])
    {
        //Do something
    }
…
```

Why doesn't it work? Do I need to initialize anything else? Or it there and easier way to generate an `[SDLK_LEFT] Keyboard event`? I've also tried `keys[SDLK_LEFT] = true;` with no succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now with the following code:

```
keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
keys[SDLK_LEFT] = TRUE;
```

After reading the keys I set them back to `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Try [`SDL_PumpEvents()`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetKeyState) before calling `SDL_GetKeyState()` again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Uint8 *key = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
    if (key[SDLK_a])
        {
        //Do something;
        }
    if (key[SDLK_d])
        {
        //Do something;
        }
```